# snakemake chose rule to run

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake

I am trying to edit a snakemake pipeline, This pipeline has a lot of rules, like:

```
rule A:
rule B:
rule C:
    ...
```

The `rule C` input is the output of B, here is a simple example:

```
rule B:
    output: 
       'path/to/output_B.txt'
    shell: 
       """
           echo "This is rule B output" > {output}
       """

rule C:
    input: 
       'path/to/output_B.txt'
    output: 
       'path/to/output_C.txt'
    shell: 
       """
           cat {input} > {output}
       """
```

My expected:

Now, I want to add a `rule D` and a params in configfile called `use_rule_D`, when `use_rule_D` be set to `true`, I want snakemake call `rule D` to generate input of `rule C` instead `rule B`

My solutions:

I add `rule D` with output `/path/to/output_D.txt` and use a function to chose the input of `rule B`, Its work

```
rule B:
    output: 
       'path/to/output_B.txt'
    shell: 
       """
           echo "This is rule B output" > {output}
       """

def get_input(config): 
    if config['use_rule_D']: 
        return 'path/to/output_D.txt'
    return 'path/to/output_B.txt'

rule C:
    input: 
       input_data=get_input(config)
    output: 
       'path/to/output_C.txt'
    shell: 
       """
           cat {input.input} > {output}
       """

rule D:
    output: 
       'path/to/output_D.txt'
    shell: 
       """
           echo "This is rule D output" > {output}
       """
```

But, there are many rule in my real snakemake script need the output of `rule B`, This means that I need to modify every relevant input. I want to create a simple method to make Snakemake generate `/path/to/output_B.txt` using different rules under different parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to add a rule D and a params in configfile called use_rule_D, when use_rule_D be set to true, I want snakemake call rule D to generate input of rule C instead rule B

One way to achieve this is to add an explicit conditional in the snakefile:

```py
if config.get("use_rule_D") is True:
    # use rule D
    rule B:
        output: 
           'path/to/output_complex.txt'
else:
    # use rule B
    rule B:
        output: 
           'path/to/output_complex.txt'
```

Note that in both cases the output is the same (`output_complex.txt`), but the execution (`shell`/`run`) is expected to be different. Having the same name for the output allows you to avoid defining conditionals for downstream rules.